# Download all the tweets from a Twitter user

Tags: twitter

I thought this was a method with which I could use to list all the tweets from a Twitter user:

```
curl -s --user-agent 'Mozilla' --insecure 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vodafone_au.xml?count=50000'
```

But it seems that if the Twitter user exceeds 200 tweets then it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea how to download all the tweets from a specific Twitter user?

Answer (score 4):

This command will get the last 3200 tweets, which is the maximum twitter let's you access.

Basically, it downloads 32 pages containing each 100 tweets.

```
curl -s --user-agent 'Mozilla' --insecure 'https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vodafone_au.xml?count=100&page=[1-32]'
```

Comment: where will the 32 pages saved?

Comment: As I mentioned here (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/34066/has-the-user-timeline-xml-address-changed-on-twitter) this user_timeline xml disappeared. Anyone knows if there is a new address or new direct method of downloading somebody's tweets without API from the command line? I asked this question here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/210415/how-to-retrieve-tweets-from-command-line).

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Twitter API docs](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline), the API is limited to 200 tweets per request.

[This thread on the twitter-development-talk mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/twitter-development-talk@googlegroups.com/2011-02/msg00215.html) suggests setting `next_cursor_str`.

There's also options called `max_id` and `page` that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You must check this link
http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_ways_to_archive_your_tweets.php

it has a lot of apps which will help you to archive **only your own** tweets!!

Answer (score -1):

**Just published (16-12-2012)**: *tweets down loadable from Twitter*

See following link: [Twitter has started rolling out the option to download all your tweets](http://thenextweb.com/twitter/2012/12/16/twitter-has-started-rolling-out-the-option-to-download-all-your-tweets/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20TheNextWeb%20%28The%20Next%20Web%20All%20Stories%29)

Comment: Yes, but that's only for **your** tweets. The OP is asking for how to download all the tweets for an arbitrary user.